# EAV indexer optimization: cannot find option

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, eav, indexing

There is a section in the Magento 2.3 documentation that is titled [**EAV indexer optimization**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/indexer-batch.html#eav-indexer-optimization). It says that you should basically disable the EAV indexer, if you are not using a MySQL based search function.

In our case we use FACT-Finder, so this would be relevant to us. However, in our Magento `2.3.2` instance, there is no **Stores** > Settings > **Configuration** > **Catalog** > **Catalog** > **Catalog Search** settings section and I cannot find the mentioned options anywhere else.

[image: Catalog Search Settings]

Also I am wondering: even if you do not use a MySQL search: shouldn't the EAV flat tables still be faster for product listings etc.?

Comment: what module you use for FACT-Finder ?

Comment: The official one: https://github.com/FACT-Finder-Web-Components/magento2-module/

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you use some custom module for FACT-Finder, and it disables ***Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search***

Upd #1

Seams this isn't [module](https://github.com/FACT-Finder-Web-Components/magento2-module); I installed it on my fresh Magento 2.3.3 and still have Catalog Search section visible. So for now, it's difficult to say what break the things.

Now I can propose you only one thing - is disable ***EAV Indexer*** directly in *core_config_data* table, by setting ***catalog/search/enable_eav_indexer*** to **0**

You can do this with

```
./bin/magento config:set catalog/search/enable_eav_indexer 0
```

Upd #2: **(answer)**

After the discussion with @fritzmg we found that Magento_Search module was disabled, and therefore configuration was missed.

Comment: I do not see any evidence of that: https://github.com/FACT-Finder-Web-Components/magento2-module/blob/develop/src/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

Comment: hm, yes I also installed the module above, and configuration is present.

Comment: can you, please, provide a screen what exactly you see under Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search ?

Comment: I have added a screenshot to the original post.

Comment: Regarding your post update: may be this is something that was added in Magento `2.3.3`? The changelog of `2.3.3` is pretty significant and also lists a lot of changes regarding indexing.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like this is a completely new option. Executing `bin/magento config:set catalog/search/enable_eav_indexer 0` on Magento `2.3.2` yields `The "catalog/search/enable_eav_indexer" path doesn't exist. Verify and try again.`.

Comment: Regarding your screenshot, you don't have  Catalog Search tab and this is absolutely strange, this tab contains very important configuration setting, such as search engine, therefore I don't think that this is differences between versions.
Btw, *catalog/search/enable_eav_indexer* come from vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/etc/adminhtml/system.xml:41, do you have *module-catalog-search* module installed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100196/discussion-between-underser-and-fritzmg).